# Passing a value to std::ifstream through constructor

Tags: c++, string, io, ifstream, assertion

I'm trying to pass a file name with a string through a constructor, my code is this. I've removed some of the unnecessary stuff for simplicity.

```
// header file

Interpreter(const std::string location);
std::ifstream *file;

// end header file

// class file

Interpreter::Interpreter(const std::string location) {
    file = new std::ifstream(location.c_str());
}

// end class file
```

However, the result is a "Debug Assertion Failed!".

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTsB9.png)

Edit:
As a fairly newbie C++ programmer (came from Java), I've taken the advice of an initializer list and this is my code now (in the header):

```
std::ifstream file;

Interpreter(const std::string location) {
    file.open(location.c_str());
}
```

Yet I'm still getting the same error, any help? Thanks!

**Edit 2:**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Interpreter *interpreter = nullptr;

    // check if arguments are provided
    if (argc > 0) {
        interpreter = new Interpreter(argv[1]);
    } else {
        // for now just use the debug script
        error("No input files, using default script (debug)");
        interpreter = new Interpreter("test.m");
    }

    interpreter->read();
    delete interpreter;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 3**

Did you mean this initializer list?

```
Interpreter::Interpreter(const std::string location): file(location) {    
}
```

**Edit 4**

Final edit, thanks guys :)
Turns out the problem was with the arguments

> And argc>0 does not mean argv[1] is safe to access.

That's in the CPP file, and still gives the same result. D:

Comment: No need for a pointer. Use an initializer list. Voila, no more need for the rule of three.

Comment: Can you show the code doing the call?

Comment: First lesson in C++ for Java programmers: Stop using `new` everywhere.

Comment: _"I've taken the advice of an initializer list and this is my code now"_ There's no ctor-initializer-list in your revised code. And `argc>0` does not mean `argv[1]` is safe to access.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sorry, didn't realize I ignored the second thing you wrote "And argc>0 does not mean argv[1] is safe to access.", turns out this was the problem after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (argc > 0) {
    interpreter = new Interpreter(argv[1]);
```

This is not correct, if `argc == 1` then `argv[1]` is out of bounds, it should be

```
if (argc > 1) {
    interpreter = new Interpreter(argv[1]);
```

As for the rest of the question, I would write the constructor like this:

```
Interpreter(const std::string location) : file(location) { }
```

(In C++11 you can construct an `fstream` from a `std::string`, if that doesn't work with your compiler then use `location.c_str()` as you had previously:

```
Interpreter(const std::string location) : file(location.c_str()) { }
```

I would write your `main` function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string file;
    // check if arguments are provided
    if (argc > 1) {
        file = argv[1];
    } else {
        // for now just use the debug script
        error("No input files, using default script (debug)");
        file = "test.m";
    }

    Interpreter interpreter(file);
    interpreter.read();
}
```

This has no `new` and `delete` and is simpler and clearer.